# Удалить объект из json

Tags: python, json

Есть json файл с данными такого типа:

```
[
  {
    "text": [
      {
        "item": "E:\\mainqueen\\Scripts\\python.exe E:/type49/python/TP/mainqueen/main.py\n",
        "time": "2020-05-27 | 19.19.52"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "html": [
      {
        "item": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9N6a-VLBa2I",
        "time": "2020-05-27 | 19.19"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "image": [
      {
        "item": "E:\\type49\\python\\TP\\mainqueen\\\\Downloads\\\\images\\\\2020-05-27-19-20-09.png",
        "time": "2020-05-27 | 19.20"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "text": [
      {
        "item": "E:\\mainqueen\\Scripts\\python.exe E:/type49/python/TP/mainqueen/main.py\n",
        "time": "2020-05-27 | 22.39.11"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "gif": [
      {
        "item": "E:\\type49\\python\\TP\\mainqueen\\\\Downloads\\\\images\\\\2020-05-27-23-25-18.gif",
        "time": "2020-05-27 | 23.25"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

И каждый объект я записываю в переменную. Как мне удалить из json объект по этой переменной? Именно весь объект, 'html', например, со всем его содержимым.

Сделал по совету из комментария:

```
def write_data_to_json(data_line):

    with open(r'data\data\saved_data.json', 'w') as data_file:
        json.dump(data_line, data_file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)


new_data = []

for i in self.data_text:
    if i != x_data_line:
        new_data.append(i)

write_data_to_json(new_data)
```

`self.data_text` - содержимое json, `x_data_line` - удаляемый объект.

Comment: надо создать новый объект, в котором не будет удаляемого элемента и сохранить его

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Фильтр по заданному ключу:

```
import json

with open('json_data.json', encoding='utf-8') as f:
    data = json.load(f)
# [{'text': [{'item': 'E:\\mainqueen\\Scripts\\python.exe E:/type49/python/TP/mainqueen/ma ...

x_data_line = 'html'
new_data = [x for x in data if x_data_line not in x]

write_data_to_json(new_data)
```

**PS.**

Строка

```
new_data = [x for x in data if x_data_line not in x]
```

тоже самое что:

```
new_data = []
for x in data:
    if x_data_line not in x:
        new_data.append(x)
```

Comment: Спасибо за приём с `new_data`. К слову, такие объекты у меня добавляются и 'html' я использую в качестве тега. Ваш способ удалит все объекты с этим тегом, я правильно понял?

Comment: @type49, именно так

Answer (score 0):

Сделал по совету @MaxU из комментария:

```
def write_data_to_json(data_line):
    with open(r'data\data\saved_data.json', 'w') as data_file:
        json.dump(data_line, data_file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)

new_data = []
for i in self.data_text:
    if i != x_data_line:
        new_data.append(i)

write_data_to_json(new_data)
```

`self.data_text` - содержимое json, `x_data_line` - удаляемый объект.